# Reports and Dashboards in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I need to add six charts to a page layout from a force.com report. All the reports are summarized with a chart. They show in the layout but I need to align them as 3 charts horizontally and 2 rows of charts vertically.

Can't seem to align the charts this way using the page layout.
How do I do this in visualforce ? Is there a free app we can use to assist with this ? 
I've seen people using iFrames but now that is not supported due to clickJacking. Is the new   apex component tag the best way to do this now ? I prefer to not code any apex classes to do something like this and we already have the reports and dashboard built in force.com.

Any examples / ideas  ??

When I preview this visualforce page I see an empty box with" To view the report chart, you need both the Run Reports permission and access to the report's folder" as the error message.

**This is working now. Had the ID ref of a dashboard which doesn't work with this. Only reports.**

```
<apex:page standardController="Audit__c" showHeader="true" >

<apex:panelGrid columns="3" id="theGrid">
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00OJ0000000e1R1" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="true" />
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00OJ0000000e2FB" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="true" />
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00OJ0000000e0o4" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="true" /> 
</apex:panelGrid>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Look into using `apex:chart` components. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chart.htm

Comment: I want to stick with the basics on this using apex component  <analytics:reportChart> and added the code and error I'm getting. Just trying to use the id of a simple report. Hopefully this works.

Comment: You should post more of your page markup. This seems like a CSS issue.

Comment: I updated the code. How do I find the 18 character ID for the report ? I would like to run this url to get the API name of a field to filter on. But it fails with the 15 character report ID. /services/data/v29.0/analytics/reports/00OJ0000000e1R1/describe

Comment: http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/salesforce-id-15-digit-18-digit-conversion/

Comment: Talked to support about this. Used the salesforce dataloader to export the Report objects which produce all the 18 char ID's .

Comment: Another interesting link to convert from 15 - 18 characters: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27686/how-can-i-convert-a-15-char-id-value-into-an-18-char-id-value

Comment: An online converter tool for the same: http://www.adminbooster.com/tool/15to18

Comment: Unless they have an API that's not going to help much in this use case. @rickmac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and it worked fine:

**VF page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Foo__c"> 
 <apex:panelGrid columns="3">
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Od0000004O4PB" />
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Od0000004O4PB" />
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Od0000004O4PB" />
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Od0000004O4PB" />
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Od0000004O4PB" />
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Od0000004O4PB" />
</apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

That was embedded in the standard page layout for `Foo__c` in a new section, 1 column

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: How can we remove the subtitle "As of .... Today at time..." on these charts ?

Comment: @rickmac - I'm going to guess you'll need jQuery to find the DOM element and then set css attribute as `display:none` - I didn't see any VF component attribute to suppress this

Comment: Yes, this is what worked:  <style> .asOfDate{display:none;} </style>