# Using Javascript to convert 15 char SF IDs to 18 char IDs

Tags: javascript, id

I'd like to create a macro for Keyboard Maestro that will take a highlighted 15 char ID and use javascript to convert it to a an 18 char ID. I understand how that conversion takes place but am a beginner at Javascript. Could anyone help in the creation of the javascript that I can use in my macro?

Thanks!

Comment: I think we need more information.  In order to convert a 15 char code to an 18 char code, you need to add 3 more characters.   Where are those characters coming from?  How do you know what 3 characters you want to add?  Are you talking about padding with spaces?

Comment: I'm wanting to append the 3 character code that can be generated from the first 15. The details are explained well here: https://astadiaemea.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/15-or-18-character-ids-in-salesforce-com-–-do-you-know-how-useful-unique-ids-are-to-your-development-effort/

Comment: See also: [How can I convert a 15 char Id value into an 18 char Id value?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27686/how-can-i-convert-a-15-char-id-value-into-an-18-char-id-value)

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I did see that but was looking specifically for a javascript version.

Comment: @Normc Added it there as well so that question can continue to be the canonical answer to this question. :) I cleaned it up there from the verbatim copy.

Comment: @Normc Did this algorithm work? If it did, accepting the answer might make it more clear for future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [one algorithm](http://www.chiragmehta.info/chirag/2009/10/02/algorithm-for-converting-15-digit-salesforce-id-to-18-digit/) (copied verbatim below).

```
function normaliseSforceID( id) { // fluff up a 15 char id to return an 18 char id
    if (id == null) return id;
    id = id.replace(/\"/g, ''); // scrub quotes from this id
    if (id.length != 15) {
        //print('well, id is not 15, bye' + id + ' ' + id.length);
        return null;
    }
    var suffix = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var flags = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            var c = id.charAt(i * 5 + j);
            if (c >= 'A' && c < = 'Z') {
                flags += 1 << j;
            }
        }
        if (flags <= 25) {
            suffix += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".charAt(flags);
        } else {
            suffix += "012345".charAt(flags-26);
        }
    }
    return id + suffix;
}
```

Note that if you are trying to do this conversion on a `Visualforce Page` you can just use `"{!CASESAFEID(idValue)}"`.